# CIImage says `Cannot render image (with an input Metal texture) using a metal context.`

Tags: swift, metal, cimage

I am attempting to convert a MTLTexture to a CGImage by adding an extension function to MTLTexture objects inside of my macOS playground.

The current function looks like this:

```
extension MTLTexture {
    func toImage() -> CGImage? {
        let context = CIContext()
        let texture = self
        let cImg = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: nil)!
        let cgImg = context.createCGImage(cImg, from: cImg.extent)!
        return cgImg
    }
}
```

However the line that is supposed to initialize cImg causes the concole to print `Cannot render image (with an input Metal texture) using a metal context.` and return nil.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey. Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same problem in iPad mini2.